# How to fix "Error installing pocketsphinx by using pip"

Tags: python, pip, pocketsphinx

all the requirements are available on my pc. visual c++ 14.6 and swig is added to the path, but still having this error

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Building wheel for pocketsphinx (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\jaxy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JAXY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lwzwibn8\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JAXY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lwzwibn8\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\JAXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ltdf0w8j'
       cwd: C:\Users\JAXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lwzwibn8\pocketsphinx\
  Complete output (7 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build_ext
  building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
  swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
  C:\swigwin-4.0.1\swig.exe -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
  Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on.
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py clean for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
    Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\jaxy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JAXY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lwzwibn8\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JAXY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lwzwibn8\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\JAXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_8lqhwz8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\jaxy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pocketsphinx'
         cwd: C:\Users\JAXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lwzwibn8\pocketsphinx\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
    swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
    C:\swigwin-4.0.1\swig.exe -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
    Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on.
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jaxy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JAXY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lwzwibn8\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JAXY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lwzwibn8\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\JAXY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_8lqhwz8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\jaxy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pocketsphinx' Check the logs for full command output.
```